# if-else combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp

I tried this code to test out the if-else combobox.

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "90")
            {
                btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
```

**Combobox setup**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Width="230" PlaceholderText="Select the following degree" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    90
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    45
                </ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
```

I have disable my "start button" at the beginning. So when I select 90 in my combox, the "start button" should be enabled right ? But it doesn't enables when  I select 90, the "start button" is still disabled. What is the error here ?

Comment: What is the value of `comboBox.SelectedItem` (according to the debugger) when you reach the `if` statement?

Comment: You should debug and check what value you are getting in `comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug/step into your program using F11. Hitting F11 once will "step into" your program. You can then continue to hit F11 which will run through your program and highlight the code that it is executing line-by-line. Once it stops, click on your "90" combo box item and continue to hit F11 until it reaches the line:

```
if(comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "90")
```

At that point, hover your mouse over "SelectedItem" and it should show you the data that is stored in that property.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Or just place a breakpoint (by clicking on the side bar on the left of the code where the pointer direction changes) on the if statement, run the app, change the combobox selection and visual studio will pause the app, and highlight the if statement. Much faster, trust me :)